# Vim slow with ruby syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby, vim

I've been using vim over ssh to work for a week or two now and all has been going great. Today I decided to add in some syntax highlighting, autocomplete, and some other general plugins. Set up vundle and went to work.

<del>My current .vimrc can be found at https://github.com/scottopell/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc</del>

I have cloned my vimrc and vim files onto my local ubuntu desktop and vim runs exactly as expected, no slowness on any files that I can find. Same plugins and same vimrc and no slowness on ruby files.

**update**

I can reproduce this issue with the following .vimrc

```
syntax on
```

and an empty `~/.vim` folder.

However, vim on this vps is very slow with ruby/haml files. Much moreso ruby files. When I open any ruby file, startup takes about 2 seconds (timed with --startuptime). With a comparable length haml file, its about .5 seconds.  This slowness isn't just on startup either, moving around and editing the file are both painfully slow.

Haml/erb(they are basically the same)

```
268.818  000.005: before starting main loop
848.871  580.053: first screen update
```

Ruby

```
199.613  000.004: before starting main loop
2937.859  2738.246: first screen update
```

Without syntax highlighting on the same ruby file as above

```
149.047  000.004: before starting main loop
152.912  003.865: first screen update
```

<del>I have tried using mosh(http://mosh.mit.edu) and it doesn't help.</del> not really relevant anymore

As you can see in my .vimrc file, I have tried a few different solutions to this problem.
I have tried running with all plugins disabled (I moved them all from `~/vim/bundle/PLUGINNAME` to `~/vim/bundle/disabled/PLUGINNAME`, is this correct?), set ruby path, set foldlevel to manual, disabled my colorscheme, nothing helps.  **see edit3**

I can post the full startupttime log for any file if that will help.
I have tested a few other languages(php, c, python, vimL) and none experience any slowdown.

---

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I am running an ssh session with ssh user@server then once inside the server I am doing vim file.rb.

**EDIT2:** I just tried accessing the server directly and the slowness persists without ssh, I have updated to reflect that this isn't a problem with ssh.

**EDIT3:** I can reproduce the issue with a .vimrc file that contains the single line `syntax on` with an empty ~/.vim folder

**EDIT4**  I uninstalled my compiled version of vim and any versions that I may have installed through apt, manually removed all vim stuff from my system, and I can run vim with `vim -u NONE /path/to/file.rb` then do :syn on and the issue will be there. The file in question is a rails controller, but like I've said, I can recreate it to some degree with most any file, but rails controllers see to be the worst.

Comment: How exactly are you running Vim over SSH? Editing files locally or remotely?

Comment: You could play with `:set ttyfast` and I believe there are a few other settings that control intention UI delays

Comment: what if you are in the actual machine? The loadtime of vim should not be influenced by ssh, because it computes all on the machine and send all the information through the network only once.

Comment: @timss I have clarified in the post, I'm editing remotely.

Comment: @demure I just tried ttyfast with no change.

Comment: @fotanus The box in question is a digitalocean vps, so I used their console access and tried it, the problem persists when doing that, so you seem to be correct, ssh is not playing a part in the problem

Comment: @ScottO Check the resource usages on one SSH window (maybe using the command `top`) while editing vim in other one and see if you get to a conclusion.

Comment: Try `let ruby_no_expensive=1` in your `.vimrc` and see if it helps your performance issue.

Comment: @fotanus top shows that vim is using huge amounts of CPU when opening the file and editing the file. I saw at one point it was using 90% cpu. Does this mean anything to you? I can't really draw any conclusions from it other than something in vim is using a lot of cpu, probable the syntax highlighter component.

Comment: @DonCruickshank Didn't help. vim still using large amounts of cpu (50-90%) when opening/editing a file.

Comment: @ScottO Could you maybe try to delete your `~/.viminfo` file? Be sure to take a backup first, for example move it to `~/.viminfo.bak` for the sake of testing. If it doesn't work, delete the newly made file and move it back. The `viminfo` file sometimes contains oddities that is hard to explain.

Comment: @timss Just tried that, deleting `viminfo` did not help unfortunately, so I put my old viminfo back and deleted the generated one.

Comment: How many lines are in the files you're editing?

Comment: @JimStewart I can recreate it to some extent with files of any size, but the one I'm using for these tests is 19 lines. None of the lines are very long, probably around 30 columns or so.

Comment: @JimStewart I was mistaken, that file is 507c, some must be whitespace because it doesn't look that long. I have tried setting synmaxcol and that does not help anything.

Comment: Since you're not getting it answered here maybe ask on #vim@freenode as well. If you're fine with using IRC, that is. If you do find the answer on other channels/sites, please do post the answer here. Good luck, I'm curious as well as to what this could be.

Comment: I'm having the similar issue, ruby/haml files are taking forever to be drawn (when opening or scrolling buffer) and load one core of my CPU up to 100% for tens of seconds. Happened today after upgrading all the packages on Arch Linux system (`pacman -Syu`). `:syn off` solves it, but I'm kind of used to colors in my sources. :-/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting causes terrible lag in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030290/syntax-highlighting-causes-terrible-lag-in-vim)

Comment: Derek Kraan - Don't think so, this issue was reproducible with `vim -u NONE`, ie, everything turned off. that issue goes away when you disable a plugin. Also it happened after this issue was fixed upstream.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The solution to this problem turned out to be the regex engine that vim uses.
The speculation on #vim on freenode is that the ruby syntax files use something that is slower on the new regex engine.

Any version older than and including Vim 7.3.969 has the old regex engine.
Add in `set re=1` to your `vimrc` to force the old regex engine on any version newer (and don't forget to reload the file you're currently editing with `:e`).

Thanks to Houl, Dolio and dmedvinsky from #vim for help figuring it out.

I haven't had a chance to try the absolute latest version, there was a commit last night that may help with this issue. I will update this if I get the chance to try the bleeding edge version again.

Comment: So it was a bug after all. Thanks for being so patient and throughout with your post, comments and answer!

Comment: having the same symptom with haml files with `syntax on` and today's vim checkout. `set re=1` fixes it! looks like the new regexp engine must be optimized?

Comment: Yep, the new vim regex engine must not like something in the ruby syntax files. I haven't seen any problems with any languages other than ruby (or syntax that include ruby such as erb or haml)

Comment: FWIW this doesn't seem to be limited to ruby - I'm using vim 7.3.1287 with the `easytags` plugin for python files and noticed a massive slowdown after it highlighted the tags - setting `re` to 1 helped in this case as well.

Comment: Using `set re=1` makes Vim even slower for me. Any other suggestions on this?

Comment: What exact version of Vim are you using?

Comment: Unfortunataly, None of all answers worked for me. I've tested it whith `vim -u NONE` and than manually enabling syntax. The problem appeared, so none of my settings or bundles is causing the problem. I'm using Vim 7.4, included patches 1-273.

Comment: I would start your own question or hop onto the vim IRC chat. This was an issue related to a very specific range of vim versions, so things here probably won't be relevant to your issue. I'm on vim 7.4a patch 1-6 and everything is okay, if you want to try out different vim versions.

Comment: **Important note**: For this to work, you *must* reload the file you are currently editing (`:e`)!

Comment: This used to work, but I am now getting an error:
`E518: Unknown option: re=1`

Vim version:
`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2015 16:22:14)`

Comment: @BrianZitzow what about `set regexpengine=1` ?

Comment: @BrianZitzow what subversion are you on? As stated in the post, anything older than [and including] 7.3.969 will NOT have this option because the new regex engine was added in revision 970 (https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fbc0d2ea1e13fb55c267b72d64046e5ef984b97f)

Comment: Holy cow! Bless you @ScottO! This is something I've struggled with off and on for YEARS! I diagnosed and profiled the issue every way I knew how. It recently reared up its ugly head again and enabling the older syntax engine seemingly fixed the lag issues I was experiencing (knock on wood). Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 17):

You should set this tw options in your vimrc:

```
set ttyfast
set lazyredraw
```

If this is not solving your problem try to start vim without your vimrc to be sure that none of your current settings are screwing it up.

```
vim -u NONE
```

Comment: I have added those two to my vimrc and it doesn't help anything. Running without my vimrc does fix the problem, but as soon as I turn syntax on its back. Not quite as bad as before, but there is definitely something noticeably wrong.

Comment: Well in this case... Happy debugging. Disable step by step every plugin and option to find out which causes the problem.

Comment: I have tried disabling all my plugins with the --noplugin switch and this still occurs. I have also tried emptying my plugins directory, the problem persists. That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Did you disabled each set option one by one? I think line 25 could be your problem

Comment: I have tried disabling everything I think could affect it. Line 25 did not help.  I just tried using a fresh .vimrc file and all I did was `syntax on` and I can recreate the problem.

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Now I can go back to VIM from Sublime, since VIM started to work much faster.

Answer (score 14):

Two things that will drastically help speed up Ruby syntax highlighting are disabling cursor line and relative number for Ruby (if you use those).

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
" Ruby is an oddball in the family, use special spacing/rules
if v:version >= 703
  " Note: Relative number is quite slow with Ruby, so is cursorline
  autocmd FileType ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 norelativenumber nocursorline
else
  autocmd FileType ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
endif
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, it was relativenumber that caused vim to be so slow in my case.

Comment: Both `relativenumber` and `cursorline` slowed things down for me. I can't probably do without `cursorline` but not `relativenumber`.

Comment: If you want to keep `relativenumber` and `cursorline` the situation could be improved with `set lazyredraw`. This not solve the issue but mitigate the slowness of cursor line highlightinga

Answer (score 8):

I'm using vim 7.4.52 and none of these solutions worked for me.

According to this github comment on the issue (https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/282#issuecomment-169837021), `foldmethod=syntax` is responsible for the slowness.

Adding this to my .vimrc finally fixed it!

```
augroup ft_rb
    au!
    " fix the SLOOOW syntax highlighting
    au FileType ruby setlocal re=1 foldmethod=manual
augroup END
```

Comment: This fixes the incredibly slow editing of ruby files I have been experiencing, where nothing else did. Instant relief. Thank you so much!

Comment: foldmethod=manual (or indent) was the correct answer for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try setting your ruby path explicitly in your vimrc:

```
let g:ruby_path="/usr/bin/ruby"
```

Comment: I use RVM for ruby, so would this then be 
`let g:ruby_path="~/.rvm/bin/ruby"`?

Comment: I just tried your suggest and my variation, neither had any effect.

Comment: This is really helpful. also because I found it cost 2.4s to search for Ruby path from the profile:    1   2.426607   0.000126       let g:ruby_default_path = s:query_path($HOME)

Comment: I have `let g:ruby_path = ''` at the moment. As long as you define this variable, you will get speed benefits.

Comment: This is the one that solved it for me. Other things didn't have any noticeable effect.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me after lots of digging around.  I used "which ruby" to figure out what to put in the path.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

see UPDATE at the bottom.

this may be helpful as a workaround -

i am using vim version

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:40:46)
>
> Included patches: 1-52

it is the stock version from
Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca.

the php.vim syntax file is not version'd that i can see, but it sez last edit'd 28 aug 13.

it isn't a ruby project, but when editing a large php class file (

```
    $ php -w test.inc | wc
    2    2410   19220
```

) i note significant delays near the top of the class, but not above or below the class, and, notably, not toward the bottom of the class.  as i attempt to insert new text near the bottom of the class, delay is minimal and seems to be proportional to the line number inside the class.  "minimal" means almost instantly, "significant" means 1 to 1.5 seconds per character.

the file is approx 1800 lines with approx 500 lines of legit php and 1300 lines of comments and doc. the class begins at approx line 30 and ends at approx line 1700.  it is conceded it's a bit large, but well documented :-\

if i insert

```
    class dummy { }
```

in front of the original "class originalName {",
there is no delay anywhere in the file.  this unsightly kluge permits vim/gvim to regain its responsiveness and could be considered a workaround.  note no linefeed between the two, just

```
    class dummy { } class originalName {
```

it can even be comment'd out:

```
    /*class dummy {}*/class originalName {
```

additional info:

1. during this test, the plugins directory was moved.
2. with "set syntax=off", the problem completely disappears.  this is NOT a fix.
3. setting the regular expression engine with

   ```
   set regexpengine=1   (or any other number)
   ```

   does not appreciably change the results.

based on these results, i would suspect the regular expression engine as well.  my point is that diddling a bit with the syntax in ruby files may lead to a workaround.

UPDATE:
i have found that the issue is "caused" by setting php_folding to 1 (enabled).  the vimrc i THOUGHT i was using was not, but at least some of the mystery is solved due to that mistake.  a simple vimrc like this will induce the problem (for me, as least):

```
    :syntax enable
    :let php_folding = 1
```

this means my issue is totally unrelated to the ruby issue, but there may be a similar thing going on with the ruby.vim file. maybe not.

apologies for the deflection.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of these solutions but what ended up working for me the best was removing any plugins associated with airline.

Comment: Try first if disabling syntax highlighting fixes it.

Comment: Disabling syntax makes it faster but I'm not interested in working without syntax enabled.

Comment: I believe, then it is actually a syntax issue. Issue number has been provided in the airline issue.