# (Mac)Vim quite slow when syntax is set to Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, vim

I'm on MacVim 7.4 (I use the command line version), installed via Homebrew.

Vim is slow when syntax highlighting Ruby code. `htop` shows a 80%-100% CPU usage when moving inside a Ruby file in vim.

I found these here on SO:

- [Vim slow with ruby syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902317/vim-slow-with-ruby-syntax-highlighting)
- [Syntax highlighting causes terrible lag in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030290/syntax-highlighting-causes-terrible-lag-in-vim)

and tried the proposed solutions. What I did:

- `set regexpengine=1`: nothing changed. Still very high CPU usage and slow performances.
- `set lazyredraw`: things are better, but the tradeoff is very noticeable (cursor disappearing while moving)
- I examined the `autocmd` statements in my `.vimrc` and found nothing slow in particular. I tried removing all the plugins but the problem is still there.

I tried turning the syntax off and, well, it solves the problem. Also, starting vim with `vim -u NONE` and then turning `syntax on` solves the problem, so it must be something in my `.vimrc` I guess?

[Here](https://github.com/whatyouhide/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc)'s a link to my `vimrc`.

### Edit

I may have found the guilty settings. It seems there are two settings that are noticeably slowing down movement in vim:

- `set relativenumber`
- `set cursorline`

Note that both of these settings trigger this behavior even alone.

These settings force vim to redraw quite a lot of stuff on the screen when scrolling holding `j` or `k`.
I doubt there's a solution here, but I'm very open to anything to speed this up.

### Edit #2

Note that `relativenumber` and `cursorline` trigger this behavior only when used in Ruby files. Every other filetype I tried (with `relativenumber` and `cursorline` on) scrolls smoothly, no matter how long.

Comment: Do have have some really long lines or a really long file?  If so there might not be much you can do...

Comment: @maerics Nope, nothing like that. See my edit for further infos.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with no .vimrc and no plugins, with only ":set relativenumber" and ":syntax on", only in ruby files. Answers below don't help, as foldlevel=manual.

Comment: FYI, I filed this issue with the vim project: https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=282

Comment: @nilbus: `:help tex-slow` recommends using two `:syn sync` settings to reduce the burden of syntax highlighting on "slow machines". Maybe it will help for ruby's complex highlighting?
`:syn sync maxlines=200 | syn sync minlines=50` Also try searching for "slow" in the syntax.txt help file for other tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting causes terrible lag in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030290/syntax-highlighting-causes-terrible-lag-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

As avivr said, Vim is sometimes slow to (especially for ins-completion) in large files due to `foldmethod=syntax`

From :help todo:

> - Slow combination of folding and PHP syntax highlighting.  Script to
>     reproduce it.  Caused by "syntax sync fromstart" in combination with patch
>     7.2.274.  (Christian Brabandt, 2010 May 27) Generally, folding with
>     'foldmethod' set to "syntax" is slow.  Do profiling to find out why.

The [FastFold plugin](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) makes it so folds are only recalculated on save (so you're always using `foldmethod=manual` -- but the folds are calculated with `foldmethod=syntax` or whatever you had set before).

This solved the problem for me. Now I can use compl-whole-line completion in my 5000 line C++ file and it's instant and snappy instead of taking minutes and unresponsive.

Comment: This may have been an issue for you, but it's unrelated to the OP's problem, as it still occurs with foldmethod=manual.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby syntax file has been known to be slow, it's better to disable 'cursorline', 'cursorcolumn' since they will cause the most effect.

However you should also have a look at [Vim slow with ruby syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902317/vim-slow-with-ruby-syntax-highlighting). Something that could potentially also help improve things.

Comment: OP posted that link as one of the things he looked at.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, also tried `set regexpengine=1` and various other things.
To me it seemed like the slowness was more or less severe depending on the size/complexity of file being edited, but it took a while to pinpoint the exact reason.

In my case the culprit was the following setting:

```
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

This setting tells Vim to create folds automatically based on syntax elements (classes, functions, conditionals).
I don't think it matters that it was set with an autocmd in this case.
I think the problem was that for fairly complex files, the folds were updated during the editing process, causing dramatic slowness for complex files.

Hope this helps someone.